# SFML Program Access violation reading location

Tags: c++, sfml

I am currently working on a 2D SFML game and I am getting an access violation that i can't seem to wrap my head around. I am getting the error while creating my `SpriteManager` class.

```
sf::Sprite *SpriteManager::getSprite(const std::string &name){
auto it = Sprites.find(name); 
if (it == Sprites.end())
{
    sf::Sprite *sp = NULL;
    sf::Texture tex;

    if (tex.loadFromFile(name)) 
    {                           //Access violation reading location
        sp->setTexture(tex);    //Get Access Violation here
        setSprite(name, sp);
    }
    else {
        return NULL;
    }

    delete tex;
    return sp;
}

return it->second;
```

The objective here is to call `getSprite("filename")` and it should check if it is already in my unordered array of Sprites, if not it should create/load the texture, assign it to the sprite, add the sprite to the array and return it.

The exact exception thrown is:

> Exception thrown at 0x0F314626 (sfml-graphics-d-2.dll) in Game.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x000000FC.

I am referencing this youtube tutorial and converting it to SFML.
https://youtu.be/9pQ99zLKDx0?t=10m20s

I also get all kinds of other errors concerning this `sf::Texture tex`. If I remove the `sp->setTexture(tex);` line i get an access writing violation at `tex.loadFromFile(name)`.
I am still fairly new to programming and I do not have much experience troubleshooting access violations. I appreciate the help.

Comment: It doesn't look like you ever point `sp` to a sf::Sprite object. You are supposed to be creating a new sf::Sprite object (`sp = new sf::Sprite();`) and THEN set its texture (`sp->setTexture(tex);`). .

Comment: Okay that works, i was confused about pointers. Im guessing SFML is not like SDL in the fact that you can free a surface after assigning it to a texture in SDL but in SFML when i delete the texture the sprite goes empty.

Comment: @Bro_Mayo_ The reason for this is so that you can re-use a texture for as many sprites as you want and you only have to load it once. The SFML documentation is really well written and worth having open while learning SFML.